# How to debug kubectl apply for kube-flannel.yml?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I'm trying to create a kubernetes cluster following the document at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

First I have installed kubeadm with docker image on Coreos (1520.9.0) inside VirtualBox with Vagrant:

```
docker run -it \
    -v /etc:/rootfs/etc \
    -v /opt:/rootfs/opt \
    -v /usr/bin:/rootfs/usr/bin \
    -e K8S_VERSION=v1.8.4 \
    -e CNI_RELEASE=v0.6.0 \
    xakra/kubeadm-installer:0.4.7 coreos
```

This was my kubeadm init:

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

When run the command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.1/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

It returns:

```
clusterrole "flannel" configured
clusterrolebinding "flannel" configured
serviceaccount "flannel" configured
configmap "kube-flannel-cfg" configured
daemonset "kube-flannel-ds" configured
```

But if I check "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces"

It returns:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-coreos1                      1/1       Running            0          18m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-coreos1            1/1       Running            0          18m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-coreos1   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          19m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-coreos1            1/1       Running            0          18m
```

With `journalctl -f -u kubelet` I can see this error: `Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d`

I suspect that something was wrong with the command `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.1/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Is there a way to know why this command doesn't work? Can I get some logs from anywhere?

Comment: hi, can you list out the files in the given directory /etc/cni/net.d ?

Comment: hi, there isn't anything in this directory

Comment: As I understand , You need to put kube-flannerl.yml manifest file in that directory. Kubelet will deploy it

Comment: I think here should be the network configuration provided by flannel yml

Comment: yea , you can try to put that flannel yaml file in that directory, hopefully it will work

Comment: Nope, the flannel manifest should not be put inside that directory. What you did is correct (kubectl apply). That directory should contain a CNI configuration file which determines the subnet for the current node. That file should be created automatically. My guess is that you forgot to specify the subnet when you run kubeadm init. Could you share the exact command you used?

Comment: thanks @whites11, I did ```kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16```

Comment: Ensure that your kubelet is using cni as the network plugin. Try with `ps -afe | grep kubelet`

Comment: I think so ```kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --fail-swap-on=false```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tonight I used [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray#readme) to provision a vagrant cluster, on CoreOS, using flannel (vxlan), and I was also mystified about how flannel could be a Pod inside Kubernetes

It turns out, [as seen here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/79417e07ca4033d162eb94d8c66a82bf8f44f9ce/roles/network_plugin/flannel/templates/cni-flannel.yml.j2#L88-L89), that they are using [flannel-cni](https://github.com/coreos/flannel-cni#readme) image [from quay.io](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/79417e07ca4033d162eb94d8c66a82bf8f44f9ce/roles/download/defaults/main.yml#L66-L67) to write out CNI files using a flannel side-car plus hostDir volume-mounts; it outputs `cni-conf.json` (that configures CNI to use flannel), and then `net-conf.json` (that configures the subnet and backend used by flannel).

I hope the jinja2 mustache syntax doesn't obfuscate the answer, but I found it very interesting to see how the Kubernetes folks chose to do it "for real" to compare and contrast against the example `DaemonSet` given in the flannel-cni README. I guess that's the long way of saying: try the descriptors in the flannel-cni README, then if it doesn't work see if they differ in some way from the known-working kubespray setup

*update:* as a concrete example, observe that [the Documentation yaml](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/v0.9.1/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml#L111) doesn't include the [`--iface=`](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/79417e07ca4033d162eb94d8c66a82bf8f44f9ce/roles/network_plugin/flannel/templates/cni-flannel.yml.j2#L68) switch, and if your Vagrant setup is using both NAT and "private_network" then it likely means flannel is binding to `eth0` (the NAT one) and not `eth1` with a more static IP. I saw that caveat mentioned in the docs, but can't immediately recall where in order to cite it

*update 2*

> Is there a way to know why this command doesn't work? Can I get some logs from anywhere?

One may almost always access the logs of a Pod (even a statically defined one such as `kube-controller-manager-coreos1`) in the same manner: `kubectl --namespace=kube-system logs kube-controller-manager-coreos1`, and in the CrashLoopBackOff circumstance, adding in the `-p` for "-p"revious will show the logs from the most recent crash (but only for a few seconds, not indefinitely), and occasionally `kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe pod kube-controller-manager-coreos1` will show helpful information in either the Events section at the bottom, or in the "Status" block near the top if it was Terminated for cause

In the case of a very bad failure, such as the apiserver failing to come up (and thus `kubectl logs` won't do anything), then ssh-ing to the Node and using a mixture of `journalctl -u kubelet.service --no-pager --lines=150` and `docker logs ${the_sha_or_name}` to try and see any error text. You will almost certainly need `docker ps -a` in the latter case to find the exited container's sha or name, but that same "only for a few seconds" applies, too, as dead containers will be pruned after some time.

In the case of vagrant, one can ssh into the VM in one of several ways:

- `vagrant ssh coreos1`
- `vagrant ssh-config > ssh-config && ssh -F ssh-config coreos1`
- or if it has a "private_network" address, such as 192.168.99.101 or such, then you can usually `ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key core@192.168.99.101` but one of the first two are almost always more convenient

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, ```kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe pod kube-controller-manager-coreos1``` gives me the error: ```mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system```. Which I think is related to kubeadmin bug https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/410 and fixed in kubernetes https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/51296